# Google maps api and https

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps API with regular key (not premier).
When connecting to my server with http, everything works fine, but when connecting with https i receive the following instead of map:

```
initialization failed please check the API key swf location, version and network availability
```

Is that because it is not premier key? can I force the google maps API to use http instead of https so that I will receive the maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https is [only supported](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#ssl) for premier maps api customers.

Comment: i tried new key that was assigned to https://dev.bla.net (original key assigned to http://dev.bla.net).

In that case i receive an error saying that the key cant be verified

Comment: there suppose to be https before the first address and http before the second

Answer (score 4):

Https in the Google Maps API is no longer restricted to Premier users. It is now available to everyone.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html